# Virtual IP failover on windows 7

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, failover, virtual-ip

i would like to find out how to set up virtual IP failover on windows 7. There are many online guides on linux heartbeat and pacemaker but i need configuration guides on how to set up virtual IP failover in windows 7.

My understanding of virtual IP failover:
Virtual IP failover assures that if a node in the cluster fails, other nodes can assume the failed node's responsibilities.

My objective:
If my loadbalancer fails, other nodes will take over the responsibility of the loadbalancer using virtual IP The end user would not notice any major difference.

Enviroment:
OS - Windows 7
Load balancer - Apache2.2
Server - Apache Tomcat7.0.14
Database - mySQL server 5.1, mySQL clustering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why aren't you using a server OS?

If you're wanting service-aware failover of a virtual IP on Windows, then the only option that I'm aware of involves running a Windows Server OS - and an enterprise edition, at that, for the clustering features.

From your list of requirements, you're not interested in any Windows specific.. anything.  You're trying to shoehorn a *nix application stack onto a Windows desktop OS - why not just use a *nix OS instead?

Comment: You don't actually need the clustering features provided by Enterprise, for this sort of thing regular old Network Load Balancing ought to work fine. You still need a Server edition of Windows, but Standard has NLB, no need for Enterprise.

Comment: if lets say i want to use NLB, can i implement this in windows 7 platform? All these are for academic purposes so i only have access to the environment listed above.

Answer (score 2):

Your setup seems to be missing a few parts.  Windows 7 doesn't have any "virtual ip failover" type setups.  If you wanted to accomplish this with Windows 7, you would probably need to have something like a reverse proxy or some other front end server in front of the Windows 7 boxes.  Without more detail, I am not sure that answering your question will be easy.

FWIW, Windows 2008 Enterprise is capable of doing what you are asking, but the setup isn't for the noob of heart..